# Control is lost when authentication pop up is displayed [Selenium + Java]

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication

I am not able to handle the authentication pop up in chrome browser as the control is lost once the Authentication window pop up is displayed.
I have tried below mentioned solutions :

> Tried with Window handlers 
>   Tried with Robot Class
>   Tried with Auto IT 
>   Tried with passing user name and password from URL

But no luck !! unfortunately unable to proceed further.

Issue is once after URL is triggered --> right after that Authentication pop is getting displayed and i have no clue where the control is going.
I am able to enter the values manually but when i run the scripts control is lost and i am unable to handle the authentication Pop up.

Your suggestions would be much aprriciated

Comment: Your popup is in an iframe? You can show us a simple example of html you have?

Comment: Able to handle it by :

Call the auto IT script first and then hit the URL 
Auto IT script will take some time to execute mean while window pop up will be opened and works as expected